# validate rewarded ad in google ad manager for web

Tags: validation, google-ad-manager, rewardedvideoad

We have a learning app with free content and subscription content.
We would like to give access to the subscription content to the users using rewarded video ads.
I can try those videos using these codes [publisher-tag 1](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/samples/display-rewarded-ad) [publisher-tag 1 2](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9116812#zippy=%2Csee-sample-code-event-descriptions-and-rewarded-web-api).

But the question here is, how can I validate that event server-side? I can't just call a function to reward the user without any validation. I'm trying to find information in google but the SSV is only explained for mobile apps (what in my opinion is less important than the web validation)

Comment: in the first documentation you shared, there is a sample for a web integration of the rewarded ad logic. I guess you need to send the javascript signal to your server using some XMLHttpRequest POST request...

Comment: @rabsom I have check the event returned and I can't find an ID or token to validate, I can't find a validation system. I think like you but I can't find anything about that, just for mobile. I can't believe that there is no way to validate that in the website, that will be stupid, it is easier to modify or hack a javascript call than a mobile logic.

Comment: I agree. Note that it is partly why adblockers are working so well... I guess you will have to create your own token system and link it to the reward javascript scenario...

Comment: create my own token system? how? that should be done by google not by my, anything I do can be faked. Are you telling me that google ads manager offers rewarded ads that can't be use because they are insecure and imposible to verify? I can't believe that, if you can verify app videos you should be able to verify somehow web videos